# Making a game, tried to make a selling to money function, it died

Tags: javascript, jquery

im making a incremental game and i made it so when i get a certain amount of "items" from clicking i can sell it for 100 dollars, to buy auto clickers. the problem is i cant figure out why this isn't working, i click the button, it doesn't work. i cant find any bugs or why it isn't working. i think the bug is that i didn't code it right, but i cant figure out what to put there, here is the code for the selling to money part of the game:

Code 1:

```
var autoPayCheck1 = {
    amount: 0,
    cost: 0,
    increment: 100
};
```

Code 2:

```
$("#autoPayCheckBuy").click(function () {
    if (totalClicks >= 50) {
        totalClicks -= 50;
        totalMoneys += 50;
        autoGarrison1.amount++;
        $("#autoPayCheck").text(autoPayCheck1.amount);
        $("#total_moneys").text(totalMoneys);
    }
});
```

please help!

Comment: what `autoGarrison1` is?

Comment: `autoGarrison1` vs `autoPayCheck1`?

Comment: 'it doesn't work' - are you getting any errors in the console? Is `autoPayCheckBuy` added to the DOM after the page has loaded? You might need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events): `$(document).on('click', '#autoPayCheckBuy', function () {...}`.

Comment: Also, where do you initialise `totalClicks` and `totalMoneys`?

Comment: i just noticed the autogarrison1 part, i never changed that. that may be the problem..

Comment: the changing of that was not the problem and there are no errors. code for total clicks and total money:                                   var totalClicks = 0;                                                    var totalMoneys = 100;